# How can I pass arguments from the console to different methods?

Tags: java, arrays, reference, command-line-arguments

The program I was asked to do was a numeric analyzer. This program looks for min, max, med, range, average, and sum. What I am trying to do is take the arguments from the input and pass them to different methods.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    NumericalAnalyzer analyzer = new NumericalAnalyzer(args);
    analyzer.calculate(); 
    analyzer.display();
}
```

take the input from `main`, then once `calculate` is called:

```
public void calculate()
{
    ascending();
    average();
    median();
    min();
    max();
    sum();
    range();
}
```

use the input in these methods, for example:

```
public void sum(//input from main here?)
{           
    int size=6;
    int sum=0;
    //have the arguments from main in the array
    int [] Array = new int [size];

    for(int num : Array) 
    {
        sum = sum+num;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of array elements is:"+sum);        
}
```

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're asking. Command line arguments are in `args[]`, so you can get access to any argument using `args[0]` or `args[2]`, etc.

Comment: I wan't the command line arguments to be used in sum.

Comment: So, do it. Write a loop: `for (String s : args) { sum += Integer.parseInt(s); }`.

Comment: What ever I put in the command line I want those values to be in the array when the method sum is called then all the method has to do is calculate it.

Comment: Thank you that was what I was asking . This is my first java program. lol

Comment: I didn't know how to use the command line values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pass arguments from th console to different methods?

The console argument is merely a String array.

You can use another string array variable to hold the input from the console and from then on, it is just a normal string array variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] input = args;
    //From now on use input anyway you like

    sum(input);
}
```

Imagine in the console, you run the program as such:

```
C:\>java myProgram 1 2 3 4
```

Upon doing the above `args` will be filled with `["1","2","3","4"]`.

If you need it for calculation, simply parse the string into integer and work with the values.

```
int[] values = new int[args.length];
for(int x=0; x<args.length; x++){
    values[x] = Integer.parseInt(args[x]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks yea this is what I was asking. :)

Comment: Just did it, it had a 5 min delay.

Comment: @maulinrodriguez no problem, thanks. You can make more post if your have other questions.